# How to efficiently do complex row operations with nested functions in R?

Tags: r, performance, loops, multidimensional-array, zoo

Given a multidimensional array, e.g. a `zoo` object `z`, with columns `a,b,c,x`. Given further a function `W(w=c(1,1,1), x)` which for example weights every column individually, but which **also DEPENDS on the specific row value in column `x`**. How to efficiently do row operations here, e.g. calculating the rowWeightedMeans?

It is known that `R::zoo` is very fast and efficient for row operations, if the function is very simple, e.g.:

```
W <- function(w) { return(w); }
z[,"wmean"] <- rowWeightedMeans(z[,1:3], w=W(c(0.1,0.5,0.3)))
```

But what if `W()` depends on a value in that row? E.g.:

```
W <- function(w, x) { return(w*x); }
z[,"wmean"] <- rowWeightedMeans(z[,1:3], w=W(c(0.1,0.5,0.3), z[,4]))
```

R complains here because it does not know how to hanlde the multi-dimensions of the arguments in the **nested** function.

The solution could be a `for(i in 1:nrow(z))` loop, and computing the values individually for every row `i`. However, for large data sets this takes a enormous amount of extra computational effort and time.

**EDIT**

Ok guys, thanks for your time and critics. I tried and tested all your answers but must admit that the actual problem was not solved or understood. For example, I hadn't ask to rewrite my weight function or calculations, because I already presented a minimal version of much more complex calculations. The issue or question here lies much deeper. So I sat back and tried to boil down the problem to the root of the evil and found a minimal working example for you without any `zoo`s, `weightedMeans`, and so on. Here you go:

```
z <- data.frame(matrix (1:20, nrow = 4))
colnames (z) <- c ("a", "b", "c", "x", "y")
z
#   a b  c  x  y
#1 1 5  9 13 17
#2 2 6 10 14 18
#3 3 7 11 15 19
#4 4 8 12 16 20

W <- function(abc, w, p) { 
  ifelse (w[1] == p, return(length(p)), return(0))
  # Please do not complain! I know this is stupid, but it is an MWE
  # and my calculations contained in W() are much more complex!
}

z[,"y"] <- W(z[,1:3], c(14,7,8), z[,"x"])
# same result: z[,"y"] <- apply(z[,1:3], 1, W, c(14,7,8), z[,"x"])
z
#  a b  c  x y
#1 1 5  9 13 4
#2 2 6 10 14 4
#3 3 7 11 15 4
#4 4 8 12 16 4

# expected outcome:
#  a b  c  x y
#1 1 5  9 13 0
#2 2 6 10 14 4
#3 3 7 11 15 0
#4 4 8 12 16 0
```

The problem I am facing is, that R passes all lines of `z[,"x"]` to the function, however, I expect it to take only the line which corresponds to the line of `z[,"y"]` that is currently processed internally when R loops through it. In this example, I expect `14==14` only in line number 2!
So: how to tell R to pass line by line to functions?

**SOLUTION**

Besides the awarded and accepted answer, I like to summarize the solution here to improve clarity and provide a better overview about the discussion.

This question was *not* about rewriting the specific function `W` (e.g. weighting). It was only about the inability of R to pass multiple row-by-row arguments to a general function. By either using `z$y <- f(z$a, z$x)` or `z$y <- apply(z$a, 1, f, z$x)`, both methods only pass the *first* argument as row-by-row, and the second argument as a complete column with all rows. It seems that this is an intrinsic behaviour of R around which we need to work around.

To solve this, the whole row needs to be passed as a single argument to a wrapper function, which in turn then applies the specific calculations on that row. Solution for the problem with the weights:

```
f <- function(x) weighted.mean(x[1:3], W(c(0.1,0.5,0.3), x[4]))
z[,"wmean"] <- apply(z[,1:4], 1, f)
```

Solution for the geenral problem with the data frame:

```
f <- function(x) W(x[1:3], c(14,7,8), x[4])
z$y <- apply(z, 1, f)
```

Brian presents also even faster methods using compiled C code in his accepted answer. Thanks to @BrianAlbertMonroe, @jaimedash and @inscaven for dealing with the poorly clarified question and for hinting to this solution.

Comment: `rowWeightedMeans` is vectorised in w....

Comment: I know, what do you want to say with that?

Comment: Just to bring this question back to life: Could there be a solution using `rollapply`, for instance?

Comment: You could calculate the weighted `rowMeans` with something like `ww = outer(z[, 4], c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)); rowSums(z[, 1:3] * ww) / rowSums(ww)`. What exactly is the actual problem you're facing? Could you provide an example? Unless the function you're using can handle the exact cases you need, you'll have to either loop by rows or find another workaround.

Comment: The primary reason your question hasn't been answered is because it is unclear what you are asking. Adding a bounty doesn't help that. See [mcve], [ask].

Comment: assume this is `matrixStats::rowWeightedMeans` ?

Comment: @jaimedash Yes. @alexis_laz Replacing mean functions with a basic calculation does not work for me, because it can not hanlde `NA`values properly.

Comment: Apply: `Returns a vector or array or list of values obtained by applying a
     function to margins of an array or matrix.`
Is this not exactly what you ask for? You can substitute whatever you wish into the `W` function I describe, but the row by row application of a function is what `apply` is built for and what my answer describes.

Comment: Added a solution with rollapply, at least for some interpretation of the earlier version of the question

Comment: `z$y <- ifelse(apply(z, 1, function(zrow) W(zrow[1:3], c(14,7,8), zrow[4])), nrow(z), 0)` produces the desired output

Comment: @inscaven That's it! Please make this suggestion an answer so that I can award it. Please remove the `ìfelse` staff, because this is specific to the function which I wanted to be treated generally. The issue is that R understands only the **FIRST** argument as row-by-row, which I have now understood. The trick then simply is to restructure the assignment: `apply(z, 1, W)`, where `W` internally calls the weighted mean function on the row elements, which are now treated as a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: To make the solution more clearer than what I just said (cannot edit anymore): The trick simply is to restructure the assignment with a wrapper function: `z$y <- apply(z, 1, f)`, where `f <- function(x) W(z[1:3], weights, z[4])`. Here, `W` could for example be equal to `weighted.mean`. Thanks also to @BrianAlbertMonroe and @jaimedash for hinting to this solution.

Comment: @Martin, glad that my comment helped you to cope with the problem. Unfortunately, I didn't post it as an answer in time, but that's not a tragedy :). I can advice you to get familiar with packages like `dplyr` and `data.table` if you haven't already, I believe that will help to improve operations over you data and make them more efficient than using `*apply` functions family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't really worked with `zoo` or `rowWeightedMeans` but if you simply apply weights to row elements before taking the mean of them, and require the weights to depend on one of the elements of the row:

```
z <- matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=4)

W <- function(row, weights){
    weights <- weights * row[4]
    row2 <- row[1:3] * weights
    sum(row2) / sum(weights)

}

w.means <- apply(z, 1, W, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3))
```

If the above gives the correct answer but you're worried about quickness write the `W` function in Rcpp or use the built in `cmpfun`,

```
N <- 10000

z <- matrix(rnorm(N),ncol=4)

# Interpreted R function
W1 <- function(row, weights){
    weights <- weights * row[4]
    row2 <- row[1:3] * weights
    mean(row2)
}

# Compiled R function
W2 <- compiler::cmpfun(W1)

# C++ function imported into R via Rcpp
Rcpp::cppFunction('double Wcpp(NumericVector row, NumericVector weights){

                                int x = row.size() ;

                                NumericVector wrow(x - 1);
                                NumericVector nweights(x - 1);

                                nweights = weights * row[x - 1];

                                for( int i = 0; i < (x-1) ; i++){
                                    wrow[i] = row[i] * nweights[i];
                                }

                                double res = sum(wrow) / sum(nweights);

                                return(res);

}')

w.means0 <- apply(z,1,W,weights=c(0.1,0.5,0.3))
w.means1 <- apply(z,1,W2,weights=c(0.1,0.5,0.3))
w.means2 <- apply(z,1,Wcpp,weights=c(0.1,0.5,0.3))

identical( w.means0, w.means1, w.means2 )

#[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
# Write the whole thing in C++
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector WM(NumericMatrix z , NumericVector weights){
                                int x = z.ncol() ;
                                int y = z.nrow() ;

                                NumericVector res(y);
                                NumericVector wrow(x - 1);

                                NumericVector nweights(x - 1);
                                double nwsum;
                                double mult;

                                for( int row = 0 ; row < y ; row++){

                                    mult = z(row,x-1);

                                    nweights = weights * mult;
                                    nwsum = sum(nweights);

                                    for( int i = 0; i < (x-1) ; i++){

                                        wrow[i] = z(row,i) * nweights[i] ;
                                    }

                                  res[row] = sum(wrow) / nwsum;

                                }

                                return(res);

}')

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    w.means0 <- apply(z,1,W1,weights=c(0.1,0.5,0.3)),
    w.means1 <- apply(z,1,W2,weights=c(0.1,0.5,0.3)),
    w.means2 <- apply(z,1,Wcpp,weights=c(0.1,0.5,0.3)),
    w.means3 <- WM(z = z, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3))
)

    Unit: microseconds
                                                      expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
   w.means0 <- apply(z, 1, W1, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)) 12114.834 12536.9330 12995.1722 12838.2805 13163.4835 15796.403   100
   w.means1 <- apply(z, 1, W2, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3))  9941.571 10286.8085 10769.7330 10410.9465 10788.6800 19526.840   100
 w.means2 <- apply(z, 1, Wcpp, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)) 10919.112 11631.5530 12849.7294 13262.9705 13707.7465 17438.524   100
         w.means3 <- WM(z = z, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3))    94.172   107.9855   146.2606   125.0075   140.2695  2089.933   100
```

EDIT:

Incorporating the `weighted.means` function slows down the computation dramatically, and does not handle missing values specially according to the help file, so you will still need to write code to manage them.

```
> z <- matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=4)

> W <- function(row, weights){
+     weights <- weights * row[4]
+     row2 <- row[1:3] * weights
+     sum(row2) / sum(weights)
+ 
+ }

> W1 <- compiler::cmpfun(W)

> W2 <- function(row, weights){
+     weights <- weights * row[4]
+     weighted.mean(row[1:3],weights)
+ }

> W3 <- compiler::cmpfun(W2)

> w.means1 <- apply(z, 1, W, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3))

> w.means2 <- apply(z, 1, W2, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3))

> identical(w.means1,w.means2)
[1] TRUE

> microbenchmark(
+   w.means1 <- apply(z, 1, W, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)),
+   w.means1 <- apply(z, 1, W1, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)),
+   w.means2 < .... [TRUNCATED] 
Unit: microseconds
                                                    expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
  w.means1 <- apply(z, 1, W, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)) 145.315 167.4550 172.8163 172.9120 180.6920 194.673   100
 w.means1 <- apply(z, 1, W1, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)) 124.087 134.3365 143.6803 137.8925 148.7145 225.459   100
 w.means2 <- apply(z, 1, W2, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)) 307.311 346.6320 356.4845 354.7325 371.7620 412.110   100
 w.means2 <- apply(z, 1, W3, weights = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3)) 280.073 308.7110 323.0156 324.1230 333.7305 407.963   100
```

Comment: For the sake of an example your code is fine. But the formula for weighted mean is different. ( [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) ).

Comment: so `sum(x * w) / sum(w)`? Easy enough to implement

Comment: Sorry, I rely on an intrinsic weighted means function to properly handle `NA` values. Using the `sum` workaround is not a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. To handle `NA` values you could use `sum(na.rm=TRUE)`. Something similar is easy to implement in `Rcpp` with `NA_REAL` and some `ifelse` statements. What exactly is the function you're using?

Comment: I want to use any function that gives the weighted mean of columns. Ofcourse `sum(x*w,na.rm=TRUE)` works if `x` contains `NA` values, but then `sum(w)` gets to big, because it hasn`t recognized the exclusion of some values in the numerator.

Comment: It seems like this pertinent information and should be included in the question, but nonetheless it is trivial to handle this case: `weights <- ifelse( is.NA(x) , NA , weights)` and then `sum(weights, is.na=T)`

Comment: You are right, even this can be implemented in C. But my question was not to rewrite the calculation! It is about the behaviour of R in passing arguments during row-by-row operations (see edit above).

Comment: +1 for the Cpp solution using loops, which I consider the fallback solution if there is no purely R solution without loops.

Comment: @BrianAlbertMonroe I finally realized very late that your post actually contains the relevant part of the final solution. I recently added more explanations in my comments on the question. If inscaven does not put an answer, I'll award yours. But it would be great if you add my explanations and replace the artificial calculation by `weighted.mean`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `zoo::rollapply`. It produces the same answer as `matrixStats::rowWeightedMeans` for the simpler case.

```
if(! require(matrixStats)) {
        install.packages('matrixStats')
        library(matrixStats)
}
if(! require(zoo)) {
        install.packages('zoo')
        library(zoo)
}
z <- zoo (matrix (1:20, nrow = 5))
colnames (z) <- c ("a", "b", "c", "x")
z$x <- 0 # so we can see an effect below...
z
##   a  b  c x
## 1 1  6 11 0
## 2 2  7 12 0
## 3 3  8 13 0
## 4 4  9 14 0
## 5 5 10 15 0

weights <- c(0.1,0.5,0.3)
W <- function (w) { return(w); }
z$wmean <- rowWeightedMeans(z[,1:3], w=W(weights))
## z[,new]<- doesn't work to create new columns in zoo
## objects
## use $

rowWeightMean_zoo <- function (r, W, weights) {
        s <- sum(W(weights))
        return(sum(r[1:3] * W(weights) / s))
}

z$wmean_zoo <- rollapply(z, width=1, by.column=FALSE,
                         function (r) rowWeightMean_zoo(r, W, weights))
z
```

For the requirement in the question, that the return value be dependent on some ancillary data in the row, `rowWeightedMeans` doesn't work. But, the function passed to rollapply can be modified to use other elements of the row.

```
W2 <- function (w, x) { return(w * x); }
# z$wmean2 <- rowWeightedMeans(z[,1:3], w=W2(c(0.1,0.5,0.3), z[,4]))
## doesn't work
## Error in rowWeightedMeans(z[, 1:3], w = W@(c(0.1, 0.5, 0.3), z[, 4])) :
##   The length of argument 'w' is does not match the number of column in 'x': 5 != 3
## In addition: Warning message:
## In `*.default`(w, x) :
##   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
## Calls: rowWeightedMeans -> W -> Ops.zoo -> NextMethod

rowWeightMean_zoo_dependent <- function (r, W, weights) {
        s <- sum(W(weights, r[4]))
        return(sum(r[1:3] * W2(weights, r[4]) / s))
}
z$wmean2_zoo <- rollapply(z, width=1, by.column=FALSE,
                         function (r) rowWeightMean_zoo_dependent(r, W2, weights))
z
##   a  b  c x     wmean wmean_zoo wmean2_zoo
## 1 1  6 11 0  7.111111  7.111111        NaN
## 2 2  7 12 0  8.111111  8.111111        NaN
## 3 3  8 13 0  9.111111  9.111111        NaN
## 4 4  9 14 0 10.111111 10.111111        NaN
## 5 5 10 15 0 11.111111 11.111111        NaN
```

Comment: This example only works because you have chosen the same number of rows and columns for your zoo object. Add a row more, e.g. `z <- zoo (matrix (1:16, nrow = 4))`, and R complains as described in the question.

Comment: Thx, I see. It would've helped if your question originally contained a MWE ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved by clever reshaping. I would use dplyr for that - but the workflow should work similar for plyr or data.table - all these packages are heavily optimized.

for this example I assume the weight function is w(x) = w0 ^ x

Here I create some sample data z, and generic weights w (note I add a row number r to z):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
N <- 10
z <- data.frame(r=1:N, a=rnorm(N), b=rnorm(N), c=rnorm(N), x=rpois(N, 5))
w <- data.frame(key=c('a','b','c'), weight=c(0.1,0.5,0.3))
```

Now the calculation would be:

```
 res <- z %>% gather(key,value,-r,-x) %>% # convert to long format, but keep row numbers and x
  left_join(w, 'key') %>%   # add generic weights
  mutate(eff_weight = weight^x) %>% # calculate effective weights
  group_by(r) %>% # group by the orignal lines for the weighted mean
  summarise(ws = sum(value*eff_weight), ww=sum(eff_weight)) %>% # calculate to helper values
  mutate(weighted_mean = ws/ww) %>% # effectively calculate the weighted mean
  select(r, weighted_mean) # remove unneccesary output

left_join(z, res) # add to the original data
```

I added some notes - but if you have trouble understanding you could evaluate res stepwise (remove tail including `%>%`) and have a look at the results.

### Update

took the challenge to find the way to do the same in base R:

```
N <- 10
z <- data.frame(a=rnorm(N), b=rnorm(N), c=rnorm(N), x=rpois(N, 5))
w <- data.frame(key=c('a','b','c'), weight=c(0.1,0.5,0.3))

long.z <- reshape(z, idvar = "row", times=c('a','b','c'),
                timevar='key',
                varying = list(c('a','b','c')), direction = "long")
compose.z <- merge(long.z,w, by='key')
compose.z2 <- within(compose.z, eff.weight <- weight^x)

sum.stat <- by(compose.z2, compose.z2$row, function(x) {sum(x$a * x$eff.weight )/sum(x$eff.weight)})

nice.data <- c(sum.stat)
```

It requires a bit more verbose function. But the same pattern can be applied.

Comment: Hi @bdecaf, I think your solution is promising, but I haven't been able to install the packages due to compatibility problems of my R version (which I am not allowed to change).

Comment: Hi @Martin. Thats unfortunate. But if one knows the vocabulary you can also do in base r. Let me lookup the functions and add to the answer.